# missing 'in' before journal title biblatex

Tags: biblatex

As stated in the title, I miss the 'In:' before the journal title. 
Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\usepackage[german, english]{babel}
\usepackage{abstract}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\renewcommand*\footnoterule{}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  isbn = false,
  doi = false,
  url = false,
  style = authoryear,
    ]
{biblatex}

\renewcommand{\postnotedelim}{\addcolon\addspace}

\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}

\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\addspace}

\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{edition}}

\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{pagetotal}}

\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{series}}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]{citetitle}{#1\isdot}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]{title}{#1\isdot}

\DeclareFieldFormat{location}{#1\addslash} %um / zwischen Orte zu setzen

\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}

\renewcommand{\multinamedelim}{\addspace\&\space} 
\renewcommand{\finalnamedelim}{\multinamedelim}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{%
  andothers = {et\addabbrvspace al\adddot},
  editors = {Hgg\adddot},
}


% kein Komma zwischen Namen und (Hrsg.)
\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace}
\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{bbx:editor}[1]{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseeditor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{editor}}
  }
    {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}
       {\bibnamedash}
       {\printnames{editor}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{editortypedelim}}%
        \usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}}%
     \usebibmacro{#1}%
     \clearname{editor}%
     \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}%
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash
     \usebibmacro{labeltitle}%
     \setunit*{\printdelim{nonameyeardelim}}}%
  \usebibmacro{date+extrayear}}
\makeatother


%Schriftenreihen in (=)
\renewbibmacro*{series+number}{%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{%
       \printtext{=\addspace}%
       \printfield{series}%
       \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
       \printfield{number}%
       \printtext{\addperiod}}
       \nopunct}}

\renewbibmacro{in:}{In:}


% Herausgeber vor Titel des Sammelbandes
\renewbibmacro*{in:}{%
  \printtext{\bibstring{in}}%
  \printunit{\intitlepunct}%
  \ifentrytype{incollection}{%
    \ifnameundef{bookauthor}
       {\ifnameundef{editor}
          {\ifnameundef{translator}
             {}
             {\printnames{translator}%
              \setunit{\addspace}%
              \usebibmacro{translator+othersstrg}%
              \clearname{translator}}}
          {\printnames{editor}%
           \setunit{\addspace}%
           \usebibmacro{editor+othersstrg}%
           \clearname{editor}}}
        {\ifnamesequal{author}{bookauthor}
           {}
           {\printnames{bookauthor}%
            \clearname{bookauthor}}}}%
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock}

%bei Journals die Heftnummer in () nach der Jahreszahlnummer
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}

\renewbibmacro*{series+number}{%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{%
     \printtext{=\addspace}%
     \printfield{series}%
     \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
     \printfield{number}%
     \printtext{\addperiod}}
     \nopunct}}


\renewbibmacro*{in:}{
  \ifentrytype{incollection}{%
  \DeclareNameAlias{editor}{first-last}
  \printtext{In:}
  \ifnameundef{editor}
    {}
    {\printnames{editor}%
     \addspace 
     \usebibmacro{editorstrg}
     \setunit{\addcomma\addspace}% 
    }%
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}
  \clearfield{maintitle}
  \clearfield{booktitle}
  \clearfield{volume}
  \clearfield{part}
  \clearname{editor}
  }
  {}%
}





\bibliography{test.bib}


\begin{document}
\title{Literaturliste}

\author{}
\date{}
\maketitle


\nocite{chomsky_noam_knowledge_1975}
\nocite{lenneberg1969explaining}
\nocite{pfau_roland_manual_2012}

\nocite{senghas2005language}

\pagebreak

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: You have two redefinitions of `in:` It seems like you want only the first one, delete the second redefinition.

Comment: Actually, three.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! Unfortunately, I'm not sure which line(s) you exactly mean. I just found my code at the internet, so I don't know how it's composed.

Comment: You have three instances of `\renewbibmacro{in:}`. Each of them overrides the previous, so only the last one is actually doing anything.

Comment: And your last definition essentially says that in case the entrytype is `incollection` do this and that, otherwise do nothing. So it is no wonder that your `article`s are missing the `In:`.

Comment: Oh yes, I missed the first redefinition of `in:`. Remove the line `\renewbibmacro{in:}{In:}` as well as the *last* instance of `\renewbibmacro*{in:}{` in you MWE. You should be left with only one `\renewbibmacro*{in:}` that does the right thing.

Answer (score 3):

You have several (three) redefinitions of the `in:` bibmacro that all do different things. Since the preamble is read sequentially, it is the last definition that 'wins' and is used throughout the document.

From your description, I guess you want the second redefinition.

You can delete the first redefinition

```
\renewbibmacro{in:}{In:}
```

and the last redefinition (which could also cause unwanted space to appear in the bibliography)

```
\renewbibmacro*{in:}{
  \ifentrytype{incollection}{%
  \DeclareNameAlias{editor}{first-last}
  \printtext{In:}
  \ifnameundef{editor}
    {}
    {\printnames{editor}%
     \addspace 
     \usebibmacro{editorstrg}
     \setunit{\addcomma\addspace}% 
    }%
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}
  \clearfield{maintitle}
  \clearfield{booktitle}
  \clearfield{volume}
  \clearfield{part}
  \clearname{editor}
  }
  {}%
}
```

So that the only redefintion of `in:` left in your document is the second one:

```
\renewbibmacro*{in:}{%
  \printtext{\bibstring{in}}%
  \printunit{\intitlepunct}%
  \ifentrytype{incollection}{%
    \ifnameundef{bookauthor}
       {\ifnameundef{editor}
          {\ifnameundef{translator}
             {}
             {\printnames{translator}%
              \setunit{\addspace}%
              \usebibmacro{translator+othersstrg}%
              \clearname{translator}}}
          {\printnames{editor}%
           \setunit{\addspace}%
           \usebibmacro{editor+othersstrg}%
           \clearname{editor}}}
        {\ifnamesequal{author}{bookauthor}
           {}
           {\printnames{bookauthor}%
            \clearname{bookauthor}}}}%
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock}
```

With a modern version of `biblatex` (>=3.8) you will not need the redefinition of `bbx:editor`, the two lines before that will be sufficient.

You also have two redefinitions of `series+number`, but they both do the same thing. They will never be used, however, since you explicitly delete the `series` field in `\AtEveryBibitem`.

I have also modernised a few other bits of code.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\usepackage[german, english]{babel}
\usepackage{abstract}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\renewcommand*\footnoterule{}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  isbn = false,
  doi = false,
  url = false,
  style = authoryear,
    ]
{biblatex}

\renewcommand{\postnotedelim}{\addcolon\addspace}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}

\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\addspace}
\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \clearfield{edition}%
  \clearfield{pagetotal}%
  \clearfield{series}%<----- Do you really want this?
}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]{citetitle}{#1\isdot}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]{title}{#1\isdot}

\DeclareDelimFormat{multilistdelim}{\addslash}
\DeclareDelimAlias{finallistdelim}{multilistdelim}

\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}

\DeclareDelimFormat{multinamedelim}{\addspace\&\space} 
\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{%
  andothers = {et\addabbrvspace al\adddot},
  editors = {Hgg\adddot},
}


% kein Komma zwischen Namen und (Hrsg.)
\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace}

% Herausgeber vor Titel des Sammelbandes
\renewbibmacro*{in:}{%
  \printtext{\bibstring{in}}%
  \printunit{\intitlepunct}%
  \ifentrytype{incollection}{%
    \ifnameundef{bookauthor}
       {\ifnameundef{editor}
          {\ifnameundef{translator}
             {}
             {\printnames{translator}%
              \setunit{\addspace}%
              \usebibmacro{translator+othersstrg}%
              \clearname{translator}}}
          {\printnames{editor}%
           \setunit{\addspace}%
           \usebibmacro{editor+othersstrg}%
           \clearname{editor}}}
        {\ifnamesequal{author}{bookauthor}
           {}
           {\printnames{bookauthor}%
            \clearname{bookauthor}}}}%
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock}

%bei Journals die Heftnummer in () nach der Jahreszahlnummer
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}

\renewbibmacro*{series+number}{%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{%
        \printtext{=\addspace}%
        \printfield{series}%
        \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
        \printfield{number}%
        \printtext{\addperiod}}%
     \nopunct}}

\bibliography{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{sigfridsson,worman,companion,aksin,nussbaum,geer,cicero}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```